# Discrepancy in line height computation; how does Bootstrap do it?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Based on my understanding of [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) and box model calculations, I believe that the height of an element, margins and all, is the sum of the following:

- margin-top
- border-top
- padding-top
- line-height = font-size * numeric line-height multiplier
- padding-bottom
- border-bottom
- margin-bottom

However, when I implement this myself, as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3us4szzL/), everything looks good in Firefox and in Chrome except for the **line-height**.

```
.btn {
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    border: 1px solid darkred;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857;
}
```

Mathematically, my font-size (14px) multiplied by the line-height (1.42857) should yield 19.99998px, which effectively rounds to 20px. However, in Firefox the resulting line height is 22px, and in Chrome the resulting line height is 19px. **What is accounting for this discrepancy?** Why am I not getting the expected 20px line height?

Inexplicably, [Bootstrap buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-buttons) appear to correctly yield 20px for the same concept in Firefox and in Chrome. I hope someone can help me understand why and how Bootstrap accomplishes this feat.

Comment: This is just a guess, but `Helvetica Neue` font gets rendered differently in FF and Chrome, so their `line-height` would be different also.

Answer (score 1):

The `line-height` is not multiplied with the font size setting, it's multiplied with the actual size of the font as rendered.

The actual size of the font is based on the font size setting, but it differs a bit depending on the font used, the font implementation, the operating system, font rendering settings, et.c.

Setting a font size like `14px` doesn't mean that the text ends up exactly 14 pixels high, rather something that is supposed to look like 14 pixels high, depending on the settings in the font. Some fonts may for example be more narrow and thin, so it would need to be rendered slightly larger than other fonts to seem like the same size. This is up to the discretion of the font designer, so it may differ somewhat from what you feel would be correct.

Also, font sizes for the graphics software are measured in points, not pixels. When you specify a size in pixels, that is translated to a point size that would give approximately that size in pixels. There is some rounding going on there, and the exact algorithm differs between browsers, so that gives a little variation.

Comment: That is simply not true – a unit-less `line-height` is explicitly permitted by the specs; and as you can see in the linked MDN article, it is even _recommended_ to use it without a unit.

Comment: Hello, @Guffa, thank you for the response, but I'm still puzzled by why Bootstrap's line heights with the same basic specs (i.e., `margin`, `padding`, `border`, `font-size`, `line-height`) consistently yield 20px for the innermost box in the box model. I'm trying to figure out what I'm wrong, or what kind of magic Bootstrap is using to achieve that consistency.

Comment: @MartyC.: They are using `box-sizing: border-box;` on everything, that affects the sizing and it might make the rounding happen to become "right".

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, @Guffa. Unfortunately I added `box-sizing: border-box;` to all elements in [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3us4szzL/1/), but I'm still not getting the same result as Bootstrap. :-(

Comment: @MartyC.: I can't find any other difference in the CSS. Are you using a doctype on your page?

Comment: From my understanding, there has been no solution to this problem at the moment. I just encountered the exact same problem, and the results are the same with or without (i.e. system font) a custom font - tested 5 different web fonts. Further, in my case, it seems to be largely affected by the font-size of an element (e.g. h1).